# Make an application believe it's in focus when is not?

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have a program who stops when I use other window. It only works when focused, and it doesn't need to be focused at all.

Is there any way to have it in background/minimized/de-focused, and keep it working?
Maybe a hack that makes it believe is on the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have two active windows at the same time.

One solution is to run this program in a virtual machine, so it can have the focus
in the guest VM, while you are doing other things on the host.